# Yaws code inside <erl></erl> not running

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am trying out Yaws, however I have run into a bump. The code inside my .yaws file is not compiling when I got to the path, instead it is being printed on the window. Here is my code and configuration:

```
<erl>
method(Arg) ->
    Rec = Arg#arg.req,
    Rec#http_request.method.

out(Arg) ->
    {ehtml, f("Method: ~s", [method(Arg)])}.
</erl>
```

Server configuration:

```
<server localhost>
    port = 8000
    listen = 127.0.0.1
    docroot = /home/something/
    dir_listings = true
    dav = true
    auth_log = true
    statistics = true
</server>
```

Any info would really be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "printed on the window"; please clarify what you expect to happen and what is actually happening. I copied and pasted your `<erl>` code into a file named `xxx.yaws`, then accessed that file through Yaws via its URL, and got the text `Method: GET` as expected, so I'm not sure what else you're expecting. You might want to read http://yaws.hyber.org/dynamic.yaws for info about using `html` and `ehtml` in .yaws pages. Also, please tell us what version of Yaws you're using.

Comment: It shows the code on my browser, that's what I meant.

Comment: You're saying you see the exact contents shown in your question, with `<erl>` tags and all? What's the name of your .yaws file, and how are you accessing it in your browser?

Comment: The output is: method(Arg) -> Rec = Arg#arg.req, Rec#http_request.method. out(Arg) -> {ehtml, f("Method: ~s" , [method(Arg)])}. . I am using Yaws 2.0.4.

Comment: When navigate to localhost:8000, it list the files in the docroot (where my example.yaws is) I then enter the path to the file: localhost:8000/example.yaws and then I see the code.Did I miss something maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `dav = true` in your server configuration, which turns on [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), a protocol for content management. Under this configuration, a `.yaws` file is treated as just a regular file, not as one that requires special Yaws processing, which is why you see the verbatim contents of the file when you access it via your browser.

Removing `dav = true` from your configuration and then restarting Yaws will make it process your `example.yaws` file as you expect.